# specify a type in the function specification in Elixir

Tags: elixir, specifications

How can I specify a type in the function specification if it can be any type that can be converted to a string?

```
@spec push(queue :: %MyQueue{}, data :: ??) :: {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "can be converted to a string", you mean the `to_string/1` function, which works for any type that has the `String.Chars` protocol implemented, you can use the type `String.Chars.t`:

```
@spec push(queue :: %MyQueue{}, data :: String.Chars.t) :: {}
```

Many functions in the `IO` module use this type in their spec, e.g. [`IO.write/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/4f3939fcc7ead60fc91ad5d1790b91f241dbd435/lib/elixir/lib/io.ex#L158).